# Difference in hour between group according ID

Tags: r

`df` dataset contain `Direction` value and mesure of `Timecode`. I Want to generate :

`Difference_begin_end`   : is the difference between the last timecode and the first of each `sample_ID` by `Direction`

`Difference_begin_end_all`    : is the difference between first et last line of each `sample_ID` by `Direction`in second.

This is df dataset :

```
df=structure(list(Sample_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Direction = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Timecode = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("", 
"17:02:10", "17:02:11", "17:02:12", "17:02:13", "17:02:15", "17:02:26", 
"17:02:47", "17:02:48", "17:02:49", "17:02:50", "17:02:59", "17:03:02", 
"17:03:03", "17:03:07", "17:03:10", "17:03:11"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sample_ID", 
"Direction", "Timecode"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT 2:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your time variable is of character or factor class, you need to convert it by `as.POSIXct()`, `strptime()`, or other similar functions in `lubridate` package. The following is my solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Sample_ID) %>%
  mutate(Timecode = as.POSIXct(Timecode, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         yellow = last(Timecode) - first(Timecode)) %>%
  group_by(Sample_ID, Direction) %>%
  mutate(red_purple = last(Timecode) - first(Timecode))

# # A tibble: 99 x 5
# # Groups:   Sample_ID, Direction [4]
#    Sample_ID Direction Timecode            yellow  red_purple
#        <int>     <int> <dttm>              <time>  <time>    
#  1         1         0 2018-12-24 17:02:10 61 secs 5 secs    
#  2         1         0 2018-12-24 17:02:10 61 secs 5 secs    
#  3         1         0 2018-12-24 17:02:10 61 secs 5 secs    
#  4         1         0 2018-12-24 17:02:10 61 secs 5 secs    
#  5         1         0 2018-12-24 17:02:10 61 secs 5 secs
```

The variables `yellow` and `red_purple` correspond to the colors of the second photo (**EDIT 2**) in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I seems great. But with larger sample data, it gives wrong values. Maybe because at the Sample_ID=1 we have group of Direction = 0 and after that Direction = 1. In the Sample 3 there is no group for direction. Please see my EDIT 2.

Comment: You said in the sample 3 there is no group for direction, but there are still Direction = 0 and Direction = 1 in your sample 3. It sounds like you want to group sample ID before Direction. Please try to revise the above code to `group_by(Sample_ID, Direction)`.

Comment: If I misunderstand, please provide a smaller sample data and tell me where the code gets wrong and what the correct values should be. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, please llok at the edit 2. Not necessary in the same dataframe, it could be another data frame with ID.